# Share model code files between client and server

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing two Python flask apps: one is the API server, tied with a database through flask-sqlalchemy, and the other one a databaseless web frontend, between the user and the API server.

I'd like to reuse the model code, for example, if I define a "House" object in the apiserver, somewhat reuse the same code to define the same object in the frontend server.

What I'm trying to achieve is, let's say I add the property "number of windows" to the "House" object, do it just once and have this change in my database model, the JSON code interchanged between apiserver and webfrontend and the output of the webfrontend.

Some possible approachs that come to my mind are:

- Somewhat automatically derive the SQLAlchemy database model from a initial shared model.
- Use as-it-is the SQLAlchemy model in the nondatabase code, so I can use the objects even if there is no database behind.

Has anyone tried any of those approachs ? any ideas ?

Comment: what's preventing you from sharing the model/configuration between the two applications ?    flask_app_A --> depends on --> mymodel, flask_app_B --> depends on --> mymodel

Comment: That would be my first bullet option: I don't know how to derive automatically a SQLAlchemy database model from a generic model

Comment: oh you want the schema to derive from the object model ?   yeah that's not a SQLAlchemy kind of thing, there might be some tools that do it but it's not really the mainstream philosophy of it (we believe in explicit schema design).

Comment: Thanks, I see. Could you give me your opinion about the other point? what do you think of working with the SQLAlchemy model code in the app that is not connected to the database? For example, just to store the "House" data received via API call, creating a temporary "House" object, without any kind of database connection. Do you think it would work? do you think is a bad practice in terms of performance or use of resources?

Comment: it's totally fine, the SQLAlchemy objects act mostly like normal Python objects when they're used in so-called "transient" mode, that is, not associated with any Session and not as the result of a SQL load.   there's some more Python overhead involving attribute operations which you'd see as more method calls in a Python profile, but for low-volume usage it shouldn't be significant.

Comment: Thanks very interesting! 

For now, I'm just sending the object data as a dictionary through JSON from the apiapp to the webapp and access it directly from the dictionary (so there's no really a need to keep the whole model updated in the webapp side). But if my needs get more complex, like adding functions to the object model that I need both in the apiapp and the webapp, I'll try the approach of using SQLAlchemy without database in the webapp.